# Phonegap Twitter Plugin Conflict

Tags: ios, cordova, twitter

I'm having issues with installing the twitter plugin on Phonegap. There must be some sort of conflict between the scripts of the plugin and my current scripts. I'm not getting any xcode or console errors. Does anyone know of any conflicts that would happen between jquery mobile and the twitter plugin? Everything works fine until I introduce the twitter plugin code into the jquery mobile framework. Here are all the assets that I'm working with:

- ios6
- phonegap 2.1.0
- jquery 1.7.1
- jquery mobile
- Facebook Plugin
- Twitter Plugin
- ChildBrowser
- PhotoSwipe

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem is the order you're putting the javascript inside of the head in your HTML. In this case try to change the order.

Comment: Good thought, I'll check into that. I'm assuming though that it shouldn't matter on the order of the plugins themselves. Right now I'm obviously putting cordova first, followed by jquery and jquery mobile. After that all the plugins just file in.

Comment: Tried different ordering and it didn't seem to solve anything. It's really quite odd, it works on the index page but nowhere else. I have all of my scripts posted on the index and the funnel into the inner pages. Any idea why it would work on the index but nowhere else?